# How to Call Spring Factory Method With Argument

Tags: java, spring

Suppose i have one factory method with String argument,and i want to call that method,then what will be the code in spring.

ex. Car.java

```
public class Car {

    public Car(){
        System.out.println("Car Instance...");
    }

    private static Car car=new Car();
    private static Audi audi=new Audi();
    private static Benz benz=new Benz();

    public static Car getCarInstance(String name){
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("audi")){
            return benz;
        }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("benz")){
            return audi;
        }else{
            return car;
        }
    } 
}
```

config.xml :

```
<bean id="car" class="com.dell.Car" factory-method="getCarInstance"></bean>
```

Comment: config.xml <bean id="car" class="com.dell.Car" factory-method="getCarInstance">
    </bean>

Answer (score 3):

Use constructor-arg like so

```
<bean id="car" class="com.dell.Car" factory-method="getCarInstance">
    <constructor-arg value="audi"/>
</bean>
```

NB. constructor-arg element is used for both constructors and factory methods

Comment: i tried with this,in that case all the beans getting loaded.